# Why does startActivity cause crash?

Tags: android

Thank you guys! The reason is somewhere simpler than I think. I feel something futility.. :
-)

I have already added activity names on androidmanifest.xml.
My code is simple.

```
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAddressActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("respond", responsebody);
        intent.putExtra("userid", txtID.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("password", txtPW.getText().toString());
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

just this.

Why are crashes caused in this code? I can't find on it.
But the more stranger thing is that crash aren't caused when I make AddAddressActivity like basic templete(source when it is made at first).
Then, is AddAddressActivity a problem?

Thanks to read my question. You could misunderstand it because of my short english. If you have something hard to understand, please ask me on comment.

Here is Logcat. I can't find reason in this text..

```
02-28 02:42:53.876: D/dalvikvm(6195): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 122K, 19% free 9983K/12192K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
02-28 02:42:53.886: I/dalvikvm-heap(6195): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.536MB for 3936016-byte allocation
02-28 02:42:53.901: D/dalvikvm(6195): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 13826K/16036K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
02-28 02:42:54.011: D/dalvikvm(6195): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 13826K/16036K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-28 02:42:54.031: I/dalvikvm-heap(6195): Grow heap (frag case) to 30.549MB for 15744016-byte allocation
02-28 02:42:54.041: D/dalvikvm(6195): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 29201K/31412K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
02-28 02:42:54.201: D/libEGL(6195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
02-28 02:42:54.201: D/libEGL(6195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
02-28 02:42:54.206: D/libEGL(6195): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
02-28 02:42:54.211: E/(6195): Device driver API match
02-28 02:42:54.211: E/(6195): Device driver API version: 23
02-28 02:42:54.211: E/(6195): User space API version: 23 
02-28 02:42:54.211: E/(6195): mali: REVISION=Linux-r3p2-01rel3 BUILD_DATE=Wed Oct 30 09:36:10 KST 2013 
02-28 02:42:54.276: D/OpenGLRenderer(6195): Enabling debug mode 0
02-28 02:43:02.696: I/webclipboard(6195): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4419e048
02-28 02:43:02.711: D/AndroidRuntime(6195): Shutting down VM
02-28 02:43:02.711: W/dalvikvm(6195): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420ac700)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mcdelivery/com.example.mcdelivery.AddAddressActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at com.example.mcdelivery.AddAddressActivity.onCreate(AddAddressActivity.java:18)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
02-28 02:43:02.721: E/AndroidRuntime(6195):     ... 11 more
02-28 02:43:02.751: V/webkit(6195): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {4419b1f0}
```

AddAddressActivity.java

```
   package com.example.mcdelivery;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class AddAddressActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addaddress);

        Intent intent=new Intent(this.getIntent());
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.mcdelivery.co.kr/kr/jsp/sys/customerLogin.do?userName=" + intent.getStringExtra("username") + "&password=" + intent.getStringExtra("password") + "&imgLogin.x=0&imgLogin.y=0");
    }

}
```

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: are you creating AddAddressActivity properly ?

Comment: post your logcat. It helps in understanding the error quickly

Comment: #2 // Yes, I added android layout xml and java class file. I am focussing on AddAddressActivity because I think that source code in AddAddressActivity influence whether the crash occurs or not.

Comment: pls post the code of AddAddressActivity, if not the logcat

Comment: @Ux5 your stacktrace does not indicate about the crash. Re run the app and post the exception part

Comment: please post your complete codes along with the logcat

Comment: @Ux5 post `AddAddressActivity.java` and indicate line 18.

Comment: the problem is in the onCreate of AddAddressActivity

Comment: Post the `onCreate()` of `AddAddressActivity` and indicate line 18. Something there is `null`.

Comment: I added source of AddAddressActivity.java. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only declared `WebView` not initialized it

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_addaddress);
webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); //missing
Intent intent= getIntent();
webview.loadUrl("https://www.mcdelivery.co.kr/kr/jsp/sys/customerLogin.do?userName=" + intent.getStringExtra("username") + "&password=" + intent.getStringExtra("password") + "&imgLogin.x=0&imgLogin.y=0");
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel something futility :'-)

Answer (score 1):

`webView` gives a `NPE` on this line

```
webview.loadUrl("https://www.mcdelivery.co.kr/kr/jsp/sys/customerLogin.do?userName=" + intent.getStringExtra("username") + "&password=" + intent.getStringExtra("password") + "&imgLogin.x=0&imgLogin.y=0");
```

Because you haven't yet initialized it. You only declare it

```
WebView webview;
```

Somewhere (before that line and after `setContentView()`) you need to initialize it

Answer (score 0):

I think that's from a bad handling of the Context belonging to your app.

Replace

`Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddAddressActivity.class);`

with

`Intent intent=new Intent(this, AddAddressActivity.class);` .

Comment: this doesnt makes any difference

Comment: I saw also that in LogCat there's a `Grow heap (frag case) to 30.550MB`are you performing a heavy loading into memory?

Comment: MainActivity.this is needed if the context comes from an innerclass. But no differences at all, the real problem here is a null somewhere.

Comment: #2 // I don't know why memory load 30MB data